# Why is the MLE a special case of the minimum contrast estimator?

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

In my statistics lecture, we had two definitions, namely

> Let $X_1,\ldots.X_n$ be iid random variables, each with density $p_{\Theta_0}(x)$. Furthermore, let $\varrho$ be a real function such that $$E_{\Theta_0}[\varrho(x,\Theta)] > E_{\Theta_0}[\varrho(x,\Theta_0)] ~~~~ \forall \Theta\neq\Theta_0. \tag{1}$$
>   Then, $$\hat{\Theta}=\operatorname{argmin}_{\Theta} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \varrho(x_i,\Theta)$$ is the *Minimum Contrast Estimator (MCE)* of $\Theta$.

and

> Let $X_1,\ldots.X_n$ be iid random variables, each with density $p_{\Theta_0}(x)$.
>   Then, $$\hat{\Theta}=\operatorname{argmax}_{\Theta} \log \prod_{i=1}^n p_\Theta(x_i)$$ is the *Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE)* of $\Theta$.

**My question.** I do understand that setting $\varrho(x,\Theta):=-\log p_\Theta(x)$ will yield the MLE as a special case of the MCE. But why does the so definied function $\varrho$ satisfy condition (1)?

**My attempt.** Writing out condition (1) for this choice of $\varrho$ yields $$\int -\log( p_\Theta(x)) p_{\Theta_0}(x) dx > \int -\log( p_{\Theta_0}(x)) p_{\Theta_0}(x) dx $$ which is equivalent to $$ \int \log\left(\frac{p_{\Theta_0}(x)}{p_\Theta(x)}\right) p_{\Theta_0}(x)dx > 0$$ meaning $$E\left[ \log\left(\frac{p_{\Theta_0}(X)}{p_\Theta(X)}\right)  \right] > 0.$$ I just don't know why this should be the case. Any hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. What you got

$$\int \log\left(\frac{p_{\Theta_0}(x)}{p_\Theta(x)}\right) p_{\Theta_0}(x)dx = E_{{\Theta_0}}\left[ \log\left(\frac{p_{\Theta_0}(X)}{p_\Theta(X)}\right)  \right] $$

is the Kullback-Leibler distance (or information divergence) (or relative entropy) between the two densities. That this is non-negative is a fundamental property, which can be proved with the Jensen inequality, or  with the log-sum inequality - see eg [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality) or [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/2006/notes/lecture-28.pdf).

Using Jensen: because $-\log(\cdot)$ is convex, we have $E[-\log(g(X))] \ge - \log(E[g(X)]$

Then $$E_{{\Theta_0}}\left[ -\log\left(\frac{p_{\Theta}(X)}{p_{\Theta_0}(X)}\right)  \right] \ge  - \log \int p_{\Theta_0}(x) \frac{p_{\Theta}(x)}{p_{\Theta_0}(x)} dx= -\log 1 = 0$$